# Trouble getting Google Domains subdomains to properly redirect to different ports

Tags: dns, server, google-domains

I recently registered a domain through Google Domains - `www.2darkpark.net` - and I'm having trouble trying to redirect subdomains to specific ports on the machine. Specifically, I want to have `mc.2darkpark.net` redirect to `www.2darkpark.net:25565`. So far, my settings look like this;[image: My resource record settings]

When I try to connect to the Minecraft server through `mc.2darkpark.net`, it fails, saying "unknown host." However, when connecting through `www.2darkpark.net:25565`, it succeeds without a hitch.

What gives? Am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

Comment: SRV records are application-specific. Minecraft Java Edition supports SRV redirects, I don't think the other editions do. What edition of Minecraft are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Java edition.

Comment: Are you sure your `SRV` record shouldn't be `_minecraft._tcp.mc` if you want if for `mc.2darkpark.net`?